# Laravel - Query a model when calling all

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Is it possible in laravel to call a collection using

```
$flights = App\Flight::all();
```

but getting all that match a query for example

```
$flights = App\Flight::all()->where('pilotID', flightCaptainId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `get()`

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('pilotID', flightCaptainId)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter() function

```
    $flights = App\Flight::all();
    $flights = $flights->filter(function($flight) use ($flightCaptainId)
                   {
                       return $flight->pilotID == $flightCaptainId;
                   });
```